# Gremlin Query to get the information about all edges in a subgraph

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am currently working on Azure Gremlin. In the problem I need to get information about all edges in single `API` call, so that I don't have to call the `API` at each node.
I am using the following query to get all the information about the nodes :

```
g.V('A').repeat(__.inE().simplePath()).emit().dedup().tree()
```

Here `A` is the root node of the subgraph. This query give all the information about the nodes but please help me with a query to get all the edges in the subgraph in single call.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query shouldn't work at all as it's invalid (unless CosmosDB supports hyperedges, which I'm pretty sure is not the case). Anyway, to get all the edges you would do:

```
g.V('A').
  repeat(__.bothE().where(without('e')).store('e').otherV()).
  cap('e')
```

If you only want to traverse incoming edges:

```
g.V('A').
  repeat(__.inE().where(without('e')).store('e').outV()).
  cap('e')
```

You can add `.unfold().valueMap()` if you're only interested in the edge properties.